# Dealing with Date Object and TimeZone in Java 7

Tags: java, date, timezone

I am developing a library to store complex data in an Object. One of the field in this object is a date. When I set the date using setter method, it is assumed that the date object is in GMT timezone. Internally, the Date is stored as a long with the number of milliseconds from epoch. In my `get()` method, I am doing the following :

```
return new Date(storedDateinMilliseconds);
```

The problem is that if anyone is calling `toString()` on the returned object, it uses the default timezone to return the date. Therefore, the returned date does not always match with the date provided in GMT. Is there a way to fix this? so that the user of this implementation will always get the GMT date when they invoke `toString()`? 
I tried the following :

```
TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
```

But this would modify the default timezone of the application using it.

Comment: Don't call `toString()`. Use a `SimpleDateFormat` to format it appropriately.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I think his problem is that " if anyone is calling toString() on the returned object,"  not that HE is calling toString().

Comment: @chrisl08 Clients can do a lot of things wrong. You, the designer, decide to return a `Date` object. What they do with it is up to them.

Comment: If you absolutely want a date combined with a timezone, don't use Date. Because a Date doesn't have a TimeZone. Use a GregorianCalendar. Or better, a joda-time DateTime. But you shouldn't bother: if a client can't understand what a Date is, and that it doesn't have a timezone, it's the client's problem, not yours.

Comment: Thanks for all the comments. I understand the java.sql.Date or java.util.Date is problematic. But I don't have control on what user would do once the Date object is returned. I wanted to understand how to set expectations.

Comment: @ToyElephant First be clear about what object it is! Your Question is not specific. A java.util.Date object and a java.sql.Date are different! One inherits from the other but the doc warns you should ignore that inheritance, as it is a bad hack. The java.sql.Date pretends to have no time-of-day but actually has "00:00:00.0". If your managers insist on using these bad classes against your recommendation, then it is not really your problem what other programmers do. This may be more of a Question for [workplace.stackexchange.com](http://workplace.stackexchange.com)! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Sotirios Delimanolis’ comment said, you are giving a java.util.Date object to the calling programmer. What she does with it is up to her. And it is up to her to understand all the goofy problems that come with that object including its [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString--) method applying the JVM’s current default time zone in generating a string representation of its date-time value.

If you want to return a date-time value with an assigned time zone, then return a different object.

## Alternative Date-Time Objects

You have at least three alternatives to returning a java.util.Date object.

### java.time

In Java 8 and later, the obvious choice is to use the new [java.time framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) ([Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html)). Give the calling programmer a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object which is basically a [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) object plus a [`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html) object.

Tip: When specifying a time zone, use a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones). Never use the 3-4 letter codes like `EST` or `IST`.

### Joda-Time

[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) was the inspiration for java.time. This 3rd-party library is excellent, and well-worn from popular use. It supports multiple versions of Java and Android too.

The [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) class is a moment on the timeline plus a time zone, similar to java.time’s `ZonedDateTime`.

### ISO 8601

A third alternative is to give the calling programmer a string representation of a date-time value. The obvious choice of formats is to use those defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard. These formats are sensible, well thought-out, and unambiguous.

> 2015-09-16T18:06:14Z

…or…

> 2015-09-16T11:06:14-07:00

Both java.time and Joda-Time use these formats by default in parsing and generating strings. The formats are wisely extended by java.time to append the proper name of the time zone in square brackets.

> > 2015-09-16T11:06:14-07:00[America/Los_Angeles]

## Never Adjust Default Time Zone

You stated that setting the default time zone affected your entire app. Wrong. It affects all code of all apps in all threads running in that JVM. Worse, it does so immediately during runtime while that other code is running.

Set the default time zone only as a last resort when all other approaches to resolve a date-time problem have been exhausted. This is rare. The usual solution is to:

- Use java.time or Joda-Time.
- Always specify the desired/expected time zone rather than rely implicitly on the default.
- Use [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) in most of your business logic, data storage, and data exchange.
- Avoid whenever possible the mess that is java.util.Date/.Calendar.

## Search StackOverflow

All of these topics have been discussed many times over on StackOverflow.com. Please search for more information and examples.

Comment: I agree with all of this except for the third bullet.  UTC may *or may not* be applicable in business logic.  Actually quite a lot of business logic focus on local dates without times or time zones, so UTC only makes sense when you're talking about a specific instant in time.  Say for example I need to know that a purchase order expires next Friday.  UTC won't help there.

Comment: @Basil : Thanks for the detailed answer.

Comment: @MattJohnson Agreed, there are times for a "local" date-time (no time zone) or a localized date-time (assign a specific time zone) in your business logic. So I added "most of" to my phrasing. But I disagree with you about degree. In my experience with business apps, most data should be in UTC, converted to a time zone only for presentation to the user (or output to reports). For a purchase order expiring on Friday I most certainly would keep that in UTC. I would get Friday at noon (or midnight, whatever) in the legally applicable time zone, then convert to UTC for storage.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you have 2 options:

Option 1. This may sound like an overkill, but you could roll out your own Date object just for this complex class of yours, and overwrite the toString() method. Maybe something like

```
public class GMTDate extends java.util.Date {

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        //return GMTDate
    }

}
```

Option 2: Keep your date as java.util.Date, but don't expose a public getter for it.  Expose instead a public getter that returns your date in GMT format, and maybe a public getter that returns your date as a long (with the number of milliseconds from epoch)

EDIT:
And a 3rd option: [AspectJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ).  You can use aspect oriented programming to intercept calls to the toString() method and return a GMT string date
Relevant Stack Overflow Question: [AspectJ: Intercept method execution/call and make it return](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20528544/aspectj-intercept-method-execution-call-and-make-it-return)